# Why am I getting NumberFormatException while converting a string to integer?

Tags: java, parsing

This is my code:

```
 public void setAreaAccessPoints(){
    String mac = "",essid = "",status = "";
    int strength = 0,kanali = 0;
    List<String> AccessPoints = new ArrayList<String>(); //i lista me ta access points
    String temp;
    try{
        String[] command = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo iwlist " + wirelessName + " scanning | grep -A5 \"Cell\" "};
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));
        while((temp = r.readLine()) != null){
            if(temp.contains("Cell")){
                String[] info = temp.split(" ");
                mac = info[3];
                System.out.println(mac);
                do{
                    temp = r.readLine();
                    if(temp.contains("ESSID:")){
                        essid = temp.replace("ESSID:","");
                    }
                    if(temp.contains("Frequency:")){
                        String[] info1 = temp.split(" ");
                        info1[3] = info1[3].replace(")","");
                        kanali = Integer.parseInt(info1[3]);
                    }
                    if(temp.contains("Mode:")){
                        status = temp.replace("Mode:","");
                    }
                    if(temp.contains("Quality=")){
                        String[] info2 = temp.split(" ");
                        info2[3] = info2[3].replace("level=","");
                        strength = Integer.parseInt(info2[3]);
                    }
                    if(temp.contains("Protocol:")){
                        temp = r.readLine();
                    }
                }while(!(temp.contains("Cell")));
                AccessPoint newAP = new AccessPoint(mac,essid,kanali,status,strength); 
                AccessPoints.add(newAP.toString());  //vazoume ta access points sti lista san strings
            }
        }
        r.close();
        for(String s : AccessPoints)
            System.out.println(s);
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

The output which i am parsing looks like this:

```
      Cell 04 - Address: 00:05:59:30:C1:7C
                Protocol:802.11b/g
                ESSID:"NA home"
                Mode:Managed
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=2/100  Signal level=-89 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
  --
      Cell 05 - Address: 00:05:59:43:AE:C9
                Protocol:802.11b/g
                ESSID:"NetFasteR IAD 2 (PSTN)"
                Mode:Managed
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=-91 dBm  Noise level=-94 dBm
  --
      Cell 06 - Address: 00:05:59:3B:C1:FA
                Protocol:802.11b/g
                ESSID:"Kpanagiotou"
                Mode:Managed
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=0/100  Signal level=-91 dBm  Noise level=-94 dBm
  --
```

The error is in the 2 lines `"strength = Integer.parseInt(info2[2]);"` and `"kanali =   Integer.parseInt(info1[3]);"` ... I can't seem to figure out where is the problem. When I am splitting the string, the info I want is in the second and third field according to the output. So why does it try to pass a `null` string for integer parsing?

StackTrace:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at askisi1.Wireless.setAreaAccessPoints(Wireless.java:213)
    at askisi1.Wireless.run(Wireless.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Well, from error message it is evident that value at info1[3] is not a valid integer. I would do System.out and make sure it is valid Integer.

Comment: It tells you the value that it can't convert - right there in the stack trace.

Comment: please give full input text .

Comment: Yep i know that it cant convert the value "".. the problem is..why does it have that value when its supposed to have the value "6)"

Comment: @Stelsawa  you have to trim() your temp string. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
Quality=2/100  Signal level=-89 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
```

contains double spaces, so in the `split` result, you have empty `String`s and the non-empty `String`s are not at the indices you think they are.

Printing out the result of `"Quality=2/100  Signal level=-89 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm".split(" ");` with indices yields

```
0: Quality=2/100
1: 
2: Signal
3: level=-89
4: dBm
5: 
6: Noise
7: level=-92
8: dBm
```

You seem to have leading spaces in your file, so the indices with nonempty `String`s would be later then.

Comment: So when i am splitting the string..how does it handle the double spaces? does it put a "" value in the info array?

Comment: Yup, exactly that. Between the two splitting tokens, there is an empty `String`, and that is put into the `split` array.

Comment: Ok i fixed that line but what about this one? Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)? This one does not contain double spaces and if i am not mistaken the value i want should be in info1[3] ("6)") correct?

Comment: The leading spaces I mentioned at the end of my answer (after the edit, admittedly).

Answer (score 1):

you are checking for something and replacing something else...

```
 if(temp.contains("Quality=")){
                    String[] info2 = temp.split(" ");
                    info2[1] = info2[1].replace("level=","");
                    strength = Integer.parseInt(info2[2]);
                }
```

Comment: temp contains the whole line of the output ( Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6) thats why i am splitting it and replacing only the part i want

Comment: @Stelsavva You like making your code unreadable dont you :). Check all the spaces you are splitting and if you are working on the right index.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have spaces in-front of the lines you are getting wrong part for to format 
without any spaces in both sides your logic is working

you could do trim() and check your result

```
 temp = r.readLine().trim();
```

For example this is working

```
String str ="Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)";
String [] str1 = str.split(" ");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str1[3].replace(")", "")));
```

Comment: in which line now your getting the exception

Comment: same lines..i printed the data of the info arrays and i indeed have a lot of trailing whitespaces..i used temp.trim() in all cases but still no result

Answer (score 0):

You remove "level=" from info2[1] and then don't do anything with it later. You should remove it from info2[2]. Also, note that they are separated by double spaces as noted in another answer here.